# WooCommerce Duplicated custom post meta values for products with variations

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

EDIT: What I need to achieve is to allow customer to leave a messages on cart page, related to each cart item, which will be displayed in cart/checkout/order...  The problem is that when I have two different variations of the same product in the cart, I am getting duplicated message (last variation message) for them.

This is segment from my code:

```
...
    foreach (WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cartItem) {
       update_post_meta($cartItem['product_id'], 'reason', $returnReason, '');
    }
...
```

**Problem:** This loop gives me duplicated custom post meta values for products with variations on cart page

**My conclusions so far:**
I understand this is happening because [update_post_meta()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_post_meta/) is updating meta values by `product_id`, and products with different variations are still the same product, with same `product_id`... so when this loop comes to second product variation, it just overwrites value given to first variation product.

**Maybe something like this could help:**
I was wondering if there is maybe a way to update post meta by product `key`, since it's unique for each product variation?

This custom info should be displayed in my cart, so maybe some kind of update_cart_item_meta() function would be helpful?

Please let me know if I should provide more information. Thanks.

Comment: How do you want to store and show your custom meta? Should it be unique per product? Or unique per variation?

Comment: Unique per cart item inside cart. If there is a same product occurring few times with different variations in cart, unique per variation.

Comment: The provided code and explanations are just too short… It's not recommended to update products meta data from cart items… I think, what you need is to save the value in order item meta data instead. So please update your question with all related code and details;

Comment: I was trying to avoid adding unnecessary code and to make my question "straight to the point" as much as I could, but now (when I found solution) I realize this foreach statement does not give enough information when it's outside of the context. I will update question and add my solution as answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I thought if custom post meta data is needed to be displayed in cart/order/email/admin orders, post meta needs to be updated with update_post_meta() function. (Now, when I'm reading this sentence, I realize how stupid assumption this was.)

Instead of post meta data, I updated cart item data with `woocommerce_get_cart_item_from_session` hook.

After that, I used `woocommerce_get_item_data` to retrieve data I stored in previous step, and to display it in cart.

In the end, I used `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` to display this data in admin area, emails etc.

**Please note that some of the hooks I mentioned above are deprecated, and should be replaced with current ones**. This is because most of the tutorials and examples I found on the web are few years old.